# Best way to move float to new register in mips?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

What is the best way to move a floating value from one register to another?

If I was working with integer and wanted to move the contents of $t0 to $t1 I would simply do

```
add  $t1, $t0, $zero
```

If I want to do the same thing with 
floting numbers I'm currently doing it like this

```
sub.s  $f1, $f0, $f0
add.s  $f1, $f0, $f1
```

Is there any better way to do this? And if someone knows there to find a good referencecard for mips WITH the floating point instructions pleas tell me.

Comment: That's not a move.  `$f0 - $f0` could produce `-0.0` (I think).  So your code might convert `-0.0` into `+0.0` or vice versa.  You did manage to avoid depending on the old contents of `$f1` being non-NaN, though, or having any dependency on the old value of `$f1`, so it's much better than if you'd used `sub.s $f1, $f1, $f1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a register-register move instruction for this:

```
mov.s $f1, $f0
```

Answer (score 0):

You requested a good link to MIPS instructions with floating-point pseudo-instructions.  Here you go.

http://www.math.unipd.it/~sperduti/ARCHITETTURE-1/mips32.pdf